# Inserting substring in ArcGIS Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, vbscript, python-parser

I'm trying to use the split tool in ArcGIS to add an underscore. Trying to make "ABC11111" look like "ABC_11111". Don't have much experience using Python or VB Script but this is what I have created with little success:

```
Split( [SURVSTR_ID] , "_", 3)(ABC).
```

Comment: Do you want to add the underscore in between C and the first "1", that is the fouth position? What is the condition/criteria where the underscore must be?

Comment: I needed to place it after the C. Thank you for your help, and below Paul has showed me the way to make the function work in VB! But thanks Delonix!

Answer (score 5):

Strings in Python are immutable, so you could use the following ([SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254445/add-string-in-a-certain-position-in-python)):

```py
!SURVSTR_ID![:3] + "_" + !SURVSTR_ID![3:]

>>> "ABC11111"[:3] + "_" + "ABC11111"[3:]
'ABC_11111'
```

Similar results with VB script (probably a cleaner way):

```py
Left([SURVSTR_ID], 3) & "_" & Mid([SURVSTR_ID],4)
```

Comment: The VB Script Worked perfectly. Thank you for your great help Paul!!

Comment: if this worked for you then please mark as the answer